# Classify the surface: $x^2+y^2-z^2+2xy-2xz-2yz-y=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I need to determine what shape the surface is and justify it.

Now wolfram alpha tells me that this particular surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid which has the general form: $\alpha x^2-\beta y^2-z=0$ but when I try to manipulate my equation by completing the square the closest I can get is this: $(x+y)^2-(x+z)^2+x^2-2yz-y=0$ which isn't quite right. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should do next?

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess, just diagonalize the quadratic form. Ignoring the linear terms (which can be dealt width by moving the origin), the quadratic terms can be written as
$$\vec{r}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&1&-1\\-1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\vec{r}$$
where $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$. In the eigenframe, the signs of the eigenvalues tell you what kind of surface you have, and the eigenvectors tell you the orientation of the principal axes (which tells you which linear combinations you need to complete the squares.

Comment: I worked out the eigenvalues to be $0, \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$ and the respective eigenvectors to be $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\ \frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\ \frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$. How does this help me classify the surface though?

Comment: @john.smith A zero signifies that you have either a cylinder-type (no dependence on a coordinate in that eigendirection, typical example of this is $x^2+y^2+0\cdot z^2=r^2$) or a paraboloid (if there is a linear leftover term in that direction, example $x^2+y^2+0\cdot z^2+{\bf z}=r^2$). The other two have a opposite signs, so it's hyperbolic in that direction. So what remains for you to do is to put it in the central form.