# Classify the surface $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2xy - 2xz - 2yz - y = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, quadrics

I am working on a problem in which I must classify the surface described by the following equation

$$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2xy - 2xz - 2yz - y = 0.$$

I have looked at this [Stack Exchange discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022842/classify-the-surface-x2y2-z22xy-2xz-2yz-y-0) (on the very same question).

Now say we let $A$ be the matrix associated with the quadratic form obtained by ignoring the term $-y$ in the equation above.

The above discussion states that, once the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ have been found, all that remains is to put 'it in the central form'.

Firstly, what does 'it' refer to (the original equation?)?

Secondly, could I have a hint as how to manipulate 'it' now that the eigenvectors and eigenvalues have been found?  I am not sure how to go about this yet.